# why conditions reduces the performance in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
aes = Model.find_all_by_id(ids, :include => {:historic_task_allocation => {:raw_allocation_incident_links => {:incident => [{:incident_type => :incident_category}, :incident_priority]}}}, :conditions => conditions)
```

when condition add it take a lot time but i removed it Quickly executed

```
conditions = ["(allocation_incident_links.valid_from IS NULL  
                 OR allocation_incident_links.valid_from < action_events.date)  
                 AND (allocation_incident_links.valid_to >= action_events.date  
                 OR allocation_incident_links.valid_to IS NULL)  
                 AND incidents.confirmed_at >= ?  
                 AND incidents.confirmed_at < ?  
                 AND ifr94.field_type = ?  
                 AND ifr94.field_id = itusf94.id
                 AND itusf94.incident_user_standard_field_id = ?
                 AND (incidents.status_code = ? OR incidents.status_code = ? OR incidents.status_code = ?) 
                 AND (incidents.incident_type_id = ?)
                 AND ifr94.incident_id = incidents.id",
                 Fri, 01 Jan 2010, Wed, 01 Jun 2016, "IncidentTypeUserStandardField", "94", 1, 4, 2, 2]
```

Note - Indexes already added in required tables

Comment: I think it is not Rails problem. Try to execute this pure sql in database directly. Maybe you are missing some indexes.

Comment: You are using so many `Join` queries in your statement through includes statement. Even though you have added indexes for them, you must remember getting a data from a single table will take less time than getting data from JOIN of multiple tables

Comment: i need to add these joins for supporting the filter but may i know if i remove the conditions  then why it works fast?

Comment: How does the generated sql differ in the 2 cases?